# PHP root folder directory - include_once and echo

Tags: php, include, root, base-url

I am struggling to figure out how to make my life easier with php by including php/html template files using the include_once ('asset/header.php') function for example. I am also wanting to use this for the css and js links on each web page.
An example being:

```
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What I want to achieve with each of these, is the ability to add a 'ROOT' or $baseURL for example before the link, so:

```
<link href="<?php $baseURL ?>/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and

```
include_once ('$baseURL/asset/header.php')
```

I KNOW that the above is nowhere near right, I am not experienced in php programming, I just know it can make my life a lot easier when it comes to document paths.
The problem I want to solve is simple:
I don't want `<img src="../../../../img/IMAGE.jpg>` and include_once `('../../../assets/header.php')`
^^ Examples here of course

I just want to put one generic code of php to print the root url before the image, css, html etc document path that it will include or import.

I have read a few instructional forums about this, but unfortunately, nothing I can figure out with my limited php experience. I would like to put the php root files in a config.php and restrict direct access if possible?

Also, I am currently using MAMP on mac. I have heard localhost may not work with some solutions, so any advice there will be great too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the $_SERVER superglobal

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/asset/header.php';
```

The realpath and dirname commands may also be of use.

Comment: So, would I not need a config.php file with this solution. How would I implement this code into an include_once statement. Just as above?
I have tried printing the php to see what the output is so I can see what it will do to a link, it simple says 'Array' with the following:
<?php echo $_SERVER; ?>

Comment: The above solution will most likely work on a server. However using MAMP is it providing a link from my doc root. so macHD > users > myname > website etc...

Comment: Add the statement to the file you want to include. You could test the path manually using echo statements to check the path is valid.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare your root variable like so:

```
$baseURL = "../.."; // or whatever it is
```

Then you can use the variable in the include like so:

```
include_once("{$baseURL}/asset/header.php"); // means include_once("../../asset/header.php");
```

Just make sure when you put the path inside of include_once, you use DOUBLE quotes and not single quotes, or else you can't incorporate variables like above.

Edit: One thing to remember, $baseURL must be in the scope of your include.  As in, if it's a global and you're using it inside of a function, make sure you declare it as a global.  More on scopes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] Function?

Example:

```
Echo("http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/asset/header.php")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
require_once '../header.php';
```